# Problem installing pdpbox, when building wheels for matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to instal pdpbox in my local computer with Windows 10 and python 3.8. It tries to install matplotlib 3.1.1 then tries with current matplotlib 3.3.4. It gives an error message.

The following happens:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: matplotlib
  Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\juanc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bl7sj8y8\\matplotlib_af49ebe1097845999252c2ef2a680b4e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\juanc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bl7sj8y8\\matplotlib_af49ebe1097845999252c2ef2a680b4e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-iem_yn01'
       cwd: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bl7sj8y8\matplotlib_af49ebe1097845999252c2ef2a680b4e\
  Complete output (499 lines):
  ================================================================================
  Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

  BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
    matplotlib: yes [3.1.1]
        python: yes [3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC
                    v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]]
      platform: yes [win32]

  OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
   sample_data: yes [installing]
         tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

  OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
           agg: yes [installing]
         tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl/Tk]
        macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

  OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
          dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  copying lib\pylab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\afm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\animation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\artist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\axis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\backend_bases.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\backend_managers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\backend_tools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\bezier.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\blocking_input.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\category.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\cm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\collections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\colorbar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\colors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\container.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\contour.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\dates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
  copying lib\matplotlib\docstring.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib

  ...

  copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui.js -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1
  copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\cmex10.afm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
  copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\LICENSE_STIX -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
  copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\classic.mplstyle -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
  copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\filesave.pdf -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
  copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\nbagg_uat.ipynb -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend
  UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\_version.py
  set build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\_version.py to '3.1.1'
  running build_ext
  building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
  Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
Installing collected packages: matplotlib, pdpbox
  Attempting uninstall: matplotlib
    Found existing installation: matplotlib 3.3.4
    Uninstalling matplotlib-3.3.4:
      Successfully uninstalled matplotlib-3.3.4
    Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\juanc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bl7sj8y8\\matplotlib_af49ebe1097845999252c2ef2a680b4e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\juanc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bl7sj8y8\\matplotlib_af49ebe1097845999252c2ef2a680b4e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bd1ttf50\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python38\Include\matplotlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bl7sj8y8\matplotlib_af49ebe1097845999252c2ef2a680b4e\
    
SAME HAPPENS HERE AS ABOVE

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\juanc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bl7sj8y8\\matplotlib_af49ebe1097845999252c2ef2a680b4e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\juanc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bl7sj8y8\\matplotlib_af49ebe1097845999252c2ef2a680b4e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bd1ttf50\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python38\Include\matplotlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Did anyone had a similar problem? I don't know how to avoid for pdp to look for older version of matplotlib. Also it may be a configuration problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem with other python libraries and it solved the problem. Any way with pdpbox I have another message error now.



`'ft2build.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib`

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32 install freetype